# transifex liked to collaboratively translate a Java project

Tags: open-source, translation

Recently, I just came across [Transifex](https://www.transifex.net/)

> Transifex is an open service allowing people to collaboratively translate software, documentation and other types of projects. Designed as a hub for translations of open source projects, Transifex supports translations straight from the project's source.

It is really cool. However, I realize that it only support **.pot** file produced by [GNU gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext)?

I am using Java properties file - [gui_en.properties](http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock/file/9a1abb05c8d9/src/org/yccheok/jstock/data/gui_en.properties) in open source project.

Is there any similar service, to translate Java application collaboratively?

I had tried to upload a properties file to Transifex. Here is my outcome.

> File you are trying to upload does not seem to belong to a known i18n format.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The head of the [self-host](http://trac.transifex.org/) version [appears to have some support](http://code.transifex.org/mainline/file/38c30730fa9f/transifex/resources/formats/javaproperties.py). You'll need to, of course, self-host it for now, until the hosted version is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Transifex supports Java Property files natively. You can find more info on the support at the [related documentation section](http://help.transifex.net/user-guide/formats.html#java-property-files).

Update: Transifex now supports [20 file formats](http://help.transifex.net/features/formats.html), including Java Properties file (Latin-1 and UTF).